# responsive CSS media query being ignored by gmail

Tags: html, css, gmail, media-queries, html-email

I'm using Gmail and chrome dev tools (responsive, 382x661) and my email template CSS is being ignored.

In the header I have:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```

My CSS:

```
@media screen and (max-device-width:500px), screen and (max-width:500px) {
/* css */
}
```

My responsive CSS is being ignored and the email template is displaying in desktop mode.

How do i solve this?

Comment: Please provide the full code

Comment: Email clients has limited support for CSS rules. Check here: https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/

Comment: @Justinas gmail should support media queries: https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css

Comment: Have you tried the hybrid method of coding? You dont need media queries for it to work on gmail app.

Answer (score 1):

**Depending on where you live and *which* Gmail client you're checking this email in, `media-queries` still may not be supported.**

In late 2016, U.S.-based Gmail accounts started to see media query support whereas U.K.-based accounts are not. U.K. has since gotten media query support, but all other parts of the world might not yet be covered.

Gmail is *also* rolling out based on Gmail product. Here is a quick breakdown of where the rollout stands now:
[image]

[More info and updated charts on Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design)

---

Regardless of where you are, there is no media query support in every Gmail client.